# client to client communication through server nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, chat

It is like I want to create a server which receives a message from one client and send it to another client.(two way communication between two clients through server) Which library in nodejs suits this? Any tutorial regarding this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: R u looking for `Socket.io`??

Comment: yes. socket.io kind of..

Comment: Then go ahead with the implementation. Google it, lots of tutorials are available..

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code you will get an idea about socket.io and two way communication.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');

// Initialize appication with route / (that means root of the application)
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var express=require('express');
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
});

// Register events on socket connection
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', from, msg);
  });
  socket.on('notifyUser', function(user){
    io.emit('notifyUser', user);
  });
});

// Listen application request on port 3000
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Here is the html file I named it as `index.html`.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Chat Application</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'/>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <span id="notifyUser"></span>
    <form id="form" action="" onsubmit="return submitfunction();" > 
      <input type="hidden" id="user" value="" /><input id="m" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="notifyTyping();" placeholder="Type yor message here.." /><input type="submit" id="button" value="Send"/> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run the server as `node app.js` and open two tabs in a browser with this api `http://localhost:3000` in bottom of the page type a message and click on send button..Hope this helps.